# Importing multiple images into excel while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to import multiple images from a directory into excel. The macro I have, thanks to Google, conforms the images to the size of the cell. What I want to do is set the height of each image to 100 px while maintaining the aspect ratio and insert it into the cell. Is that possible?

This the Macro I found:

```
Sub InsertPictures()
Dim PicList() As Variant
Dim PicFormat As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim sShape As Shape
On Error Resume Next
PicList = Application.GetOpenFilename(PicFormat, MultiSelect:=True)
xColIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
If IsArray(PicList) Then
    xRowIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Row
    For lLoop = LBound(PicList) To UBound(PicList)
        Set Rng = Cells(xRowIndex, xColIndex)
        Set sShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicList(lLoop), msoFalse, msoCTrue, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width, Rng.Height)
        xRowIndex = xRowIndex + 1
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

PS. I found kutools for excel which inserts images but forces me to define a particular height and width values. Did I miss the option of maintaining the aspect ratio in kutools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not fond of the code you found on Google, I modified it to meet your requirements:

```
Sub InsertPictures()
    Dim PicList() As Variant
    Dim PicFormat As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim sShape As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
    PicList = Application.GetOpenFilename(PicFormat, MultiSelect:=True)
    xColIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
    If IsArray(PicList) Then
        xRowIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Row
        For lLoop = LBound(PicList) To UBound(PicList)
            Set Rng = Cells(xRowIndex, xColIndex)
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicList(lLoop), msoFalse, msoCTrue, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, -1, -1)
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Height = 100 * 3 / 4
                Rng.RowHeight = .Height
                Rng.ColumnWidth = .Width / Rng.Width * Rng.ColumnWidth
                Rng.ColumnWidth = .Width / Rng.Width * Rng.ColumnWidth
                Rng.ColumnWidth = .Width / Rng.Width * Rng.ColumnWidth
            End With
            xRowIndex = xRowIndex + 1
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this will result in 100 pixel high images only on a monitor that has 72 dots per inch. It is possible to do this for higher density displays but requires an API call.

Note also that the line repeated three times is NOT a typo. There is an idiosyncrasy regarding setting Excel column widths that requires this unusual practice.

**UPDATE**

You requested an update that will center the images as well. The following version will do just that:

```
Sub InsertPictures()
    Dim PicList() As Variant
    Dim PicFormat As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim sShape As Shape
    Dim MaxWidth#
    On Error Resume Next
    PicList = Application.GetOpenFilename(PicFormat, MultiSelect:=True)
    xColIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
    If IsArray(PicList) Then
        xRowIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Row
        For lLoop = LBound(PicList) To UBound(PicList)
            Set Rng = Cells(xRowIndex, xColIndex)
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicList(lLoop), msoFalse, msoCTrue, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, -1, -1)
                .LockAspectRatio = True
                .Height = 100 * 3 / 4
                Rng.RowHeight = .Height
                If MaxWidth < .Width Then
                    MaxWidth = .Width
                End If
            End With
            xRowIndex = xRowIndex + 1
        Next
        Rng.ColumnWidth = MaxWidth / Rng.Width * Rng.ColumnWidth
        Rng.ColumnWidth = MaxWidth / Rng.Width * Rng.ColumnWidth
        Rng.ColumnWidth = MaxWidth / Rng.Width * Rng.ColumnWidth
        For Each sShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            sShape.Left = MaxWidth / 2 - sShape.Width / 2
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much that did work. One question: Will it be possible to center the image horizontally?

Comment: Yup just what I wanted. Thank you so much! :)